# Is this usage of "aren't" proper English?

Tags: grammaticality, contractions, negation

> Aren't you going to go outside?

My wife insists this is improper English, *Hillbilly speak*, she calls it. The proper way to ask, she says, is *Are you going to go outside?*

I say it's the same as asking *Won't you play with me?*, which I do not find offensive.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's anything wrong with it.  It's a contraction of *Are you not going to go outside?*, which is perfectly acceptable; the addition of the negation changes the expectation conveyed by the sentence to imply that the speaker thought the subject *was* going to go outside.  This is useful, and it's as meaningful to ask about an event *not* occurring as it is to ask about it occurring.

I suspect that your wife's problem is really with the *sound* of the word "aren't", especially when pronounced as one syllable.  (*Ahr-ənt* sounds passably okay, *arnt* sounds hickish and suggestive of the dreaded *ain't*.)

Comment: +1 particularly for the presumption implicit in the question.

Comment: *Aren't* can be pronounced as two syllables?  News to me.  Also, *ain't* is incredibly standard in London. :-)

Comment: @Orbling: Sure, you just slow it down a little.  And of course it's standard in London, London is full of chavs. :)

Comment: Oi! Who are you calli.. actually you're right.  [I can slow it down, but then it sounds wrong.]

Answer (score 3):

To start a question with *aren't* is perfectly acceptable.

Using the negation in some questions can give to the question a different meaning, and the question could be interpreted as a suggestion.

> Aren't you going inside? — The suggestion is to go inside.
>   Didn't you mean to call Frank? - The suggestion is to call Frank.

Answer (score 2):

To express a question when not knowing someone's will I would use the more familiar

> Are you going inside?

The problem with

> Are you not going inside?

is the ambiguity of the single-word-answer "No" along with a double-negative.  "No you are not" or "No you are not 'not going' "?

I am no scholar but I am a Hillbilly. We normally just say something like "Ain't ya goin' on in?" which is just horrible in most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Contractions such as "aren't", for example, should only be used in casual/informal speech/writing.  So, the answer is that it depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

As a foreign English student, my teacher told us the following two facts.

> Aren't you going inside

This is a suggestion; it suggests that you go inside.

> Are you not going inside

This is really a question. You don't know someone's will, so you ask.

PS: Correction for my English is welcome :)